# commitEditingStyle: delete data but continue to display row

Tags: ios, uitableview, delete-row

> I want to delete the row of my `tableView`. I can delete the row from database but the row in my tableview does not dissapear.
>   Thanks a lot!!!
>   Mayte

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {


        // Delete the row from the data source
        PFUser *user = [self.allProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [_mipedido removeObject:[PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"almacen"objectId:user.objectId]];
        [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];


        NSMutableArray *pedido = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
        {
            [pedido removeObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:1]];
        }

        [tableView beginUpdates];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:pedido withRowAnimation:NO];

        [tableView endUpdates];
     }

    [tableView reloadData];

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"editSnacksTableViewCell";
    editSnacksTableViewCell*cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib =[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"editSnacks" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    PFUser *user = [self.allProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.precio.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[precioProducto text] doubleValue]];

    cell.nombreProducto.text =user[@"nombreProducto"];

//   cell.photoSnacks.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
//    cell.descripcionSnakcs.text =[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    self.mipedido = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"mipedido"];

    PFQuery *query = [self.mipedido query];
    //    [query whereKey:@"nombreProducto" notEqualTo:self.currentUser.username];
    [query orderByAscending:@"nombreProducto"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
        else {
            self.allProducts =objects;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }];

}
```

Comment: As you are saving in the background, it could be that it did not have the time to save before you read the database again. Try saving synchronously

Comment: Ignacy, Thank you so much for interest in my problem. Actually, I reach to change my code and finally I dont have any crash but I continue to see the row that I delete recently. I think it something about refreshing. I use Parse in vviewWillAppear. I dont know if this cause this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are index path objects added to `pedido`?

Comment: Hello Steven, Thank so much for try to help me. Pedido is NSMutableArray related to "mipedido". I have another property: allProducts that is the array. I hope understand your question. I added more code in my question to try to be more clear. Thanks indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The calls for the tableview to reload data and begin and updates are not needed because the  deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: handles this part. Therefore your code should look like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) { 
       // Delete the row from the data source
       PFUser *user = [self.allProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       [_mipedido removeObject:[PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"almacen"objectId:user.objectId]];
       [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];


       NSMutableArray *pedido = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
       //Why use a loop? can't you just put 0 instead of i in the remove object?
       for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
       {
           //pedido is empty as it was just initiated. There is nothing to remove.
           [pedido removeObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:1]];
       }
       //the NSMutableArray does not contain any index paths so it will not delete anything.
       [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:pedido withRowAnimation:NO];
  }
}
```

Also, you will never remove an object from the database as you are trying to remove an invalid index path (pedido) as pedido is an empty initiated mutable array, not containing any index paths. Therefore the tableView will not delete a row.

In order to delete the indexPath the user swiped, use:

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:NO];
```

Overall, the code, if the database that you read from is _mipedido, should look like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) { 
       // Delete the row from the data source
       PFUser *user = [self.allProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       [_mipedido removeObject:[PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"almacen"objectId:user.objectId]];
       [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
       //delete correct row from tableView
       [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:NO];
  }
}
```

Comment: Ignacy. Once again thank you so much for try to help me. You are right in all that you told. I change my code as you tell me but I have the same result. So I guess the problem is in refresh the tableview display. And I am scared that perhaps is in my viewWillAppear method that I wrote. I attach the method.

Comment: `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    self.mipedido = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"mipedido"]; 
    PFQuery *query = [self.mipedido query];
    [query orderByAscending:@"nombreProducto"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
        else {
            self.allProducts =objects;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }];
}
`

Comment: @maytelabarga would be more useful to see the tableview data source (cellForRowAtIndexPath) can you add it to your question?

Comment: @maytelabarga you are deleting the entry from _mipedido but read from user using line  'PFUser *user = [self.allProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];'    You need to remove the user from the database, as that is where it is being read from

Comment: Sorry Ignacy. I did not understand that you told me. Remove user means -in my code- PFUser from Parse. By the way, I try to change this line with mipedido entry but I can not delete the product in Parse.

Comment: Why can you not delete the product in parse? is it that you don't wan't to or is the code not working?

Comment: When i remove user from my Code. Code not working so the product in Parse is not delete. This is the reason behause i can not change the three first Lines of my code. Thanks for this Feedback

Comment: @maytelabarga use `[[PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"almacen"objectId:user.objectId] deleteInBackground];` also have a look at the [parse documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-deleting/iOS)

Comment: Ignacy, one again thank you for your help. I did that you wrote me. In fact, I would like to delete the products from my PFRelation. I have my user and almacen related in mipedido and from there, I want to delete the items. So when I run your code I delete the item but as well my main productlist.